# How can I check which type an argument passed as a union type is?

Tags: typescript

I have data for charting that may be in a couple different forms:

```
1DChartPoint = { x: number }
2DChartPoint extends 1DChartPoint = { y: number }
3DChartPoint extends 2DChartPoint = { z: number }

DataSet<T extends 1DChartPoint> = {data: number[] | T[]}

BarChartDataSet extends DataSet<1DChartPoint>
ScatterplotDataSet extends DataSet<2DChartPoint>
BubbleplotDataSet extends DataSet<3DChartPoint>
```

Then, I want to convert whatever dataset comes in to chart.js's `ChartData` object:

```
private convert<T extends 1DChartPoint>(data: DataSet<T>) {
  let convertedData;

  if (data is number[]) {
    convertedData = data
  } else if (data is 1DChartPoint) {
    convertedData = data.map(val => val.x);
  }

  const result: chartjs.ChartData = {
    datasets: [convertedData]
  }

return result;
```

What's the right mechanism to check whether `data` is either a `number[]` or a `1DChartPoint`, and use `data` or `data.x` appropriately?

Comment: Could you provide a non-pseudocode self-contained [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without being distracted by errors or other problems unrelated to your question?  That would make it easier for us to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a typeguard to narrow data into `number[]` or `1DChartPoint`.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
const isNumberArray = (val: number[] | 1DChartPoint[]): val is number[] => {
   if(val.length < 1) return false;
   else {
     return typeof val[0] === 'number'
   }
}
```

Then in your data processing code:

```
if (isNumberArray(data)) {
    convertedData = data
  } else {
    convertedData = data.map(val => val.x);
  }
```

Sample you can run on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=46&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5TABQPahgCMAIsgN7IBQyyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbTUC%20A3FSoI8IAM5hkwUQDl2XKAEEoUOAE9kAXmQAKAG5wANk1adoAbQC6yAD5pM2fIVKWAlE30HJo5nPNWNAHwUNLTAMHqGAHQGECAA5mDoyAA8yEQuyFAQYCxQIMjwBqIQArTIEEUo5CFlWTl5yGCqAA4QeDDIHmYADP4aWgDkJvIDNTxU40Ii4sjNBOCiTBhYuPPEJJaayGbVtIxpAEwTADRUu-RMRADMExYCU2ISJt5aZkTHV8cALBaCwo-lNjNJrGXxQTavX4PUR4GLRPBxbQAA0cCyYABJyFJZKZFMo1No5oRRC4eEiXNDYRB4YikTjFshMdiwUoVKptM9SeTKXCDAjkQBRIEgxlYmQs-HsiDC1RclxAA):

```
interface ChartPoint1D { 
  x: number 
};

const isNumberArray = (val: number[] | ChartPoint1D[]): val is number[] => {
   if(val.length < 1) return false;
   else {
     return typeof val[0] === 'number'
   }
}

const points: ChartPoint1D[] = [{
  x: 12
},
{
  x: 13
}];

const nums = [1,3,4]

const empty: number[] = []

console.log(`Points: ${isNumberArray(points)}`)
console.log(`Nums: ${isNumberArray(nums)}`)
console.log(`Empty: ${isNumberArray(empty)}`)
```